# How can I set to run Visual Studio 2013 using command in Run window when Visual Studio 2010 is also installed in the same Machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I installed VS 2013 in my machine which already had visual studio 2010 installed. When I run 'devenv' command from Run window, it opens Visual Studio 2010. What should I do to open Visual Studio 2013 instead of 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these steps :

1- Goto "`system properties`" (by searching "`environment variables`" and clicking "`Edit the system environment variables`" on windows 8)

2- In the shown window goto "`Advanced`" tab and then click on "`Environment Variables`"

3- In "`System Variables`" find the "`Path`" variable and then click "`Edit`"

4- (Copy the "`Variable value`" into "`Notepad`" to have a better view) and then search for any "VS 2010" related phrases and remove them from the string if any

5- Add the your Vs 2013 IDE path into it (consider semicolon separator) like this :

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
```

6- Save it and close all the windows

7- Run the Command all the things should be ok!

**NOTE** : As I tested you should type **`devenv.exe`** to run it not `devenv` with no extention!